# Third party click tracking with DoubleClick

Tags: ads, double-click-advertising

Can someone help me with doing third-party click tracking with DoubleClick click tracking URLs?

For e.g. the DoubleClick click tracking URL is :

http://ad.mo.doubleclick.net/dartproxy/dfa.click.handler?k=N1707.540589.COMPANY.COM/B6899033.6;ord=1897438579

How can I ensure that my in-house click tracking URL say http://myserver.com/click?token=value gets invoked when this DoubleClick click tracking URL is called?

Answer (score 1):

You can append a click= parameter to the URL and DoubleClick will redirect to that URL and append the final URL at the end of the URL.

For instance if your url was http://myserver.com/click?token=value&url= they would append the final url to the end of the URL so that you can redirect to the final destination.

If you are curious about other trackers we detail the main ones here:

http://help.adzerk.com/questions/6539-Third-Party-Click-Tracking

Comment: will the click tracker tag work in the same way even if I change the click-through URL in tag, is it still going to count the click on it?